# Transfer my whtsapp data from android to windows phone

Tags: whatsapp, update, video

If I make a back up my whatsapp data in google drive can i get it restored it in my windows phone by google drive ?
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

**No it is not possible.**

---

For some reason WhatsApp has different backup formats for Android ad Windows phone making this difficult. In Android the backups are stored in a single file with the extension *.db.crypt12*. But on Windows phone the backup is stored into 3 different files namely *calls.db, messages.db, settings.db*.

As far as I know it is not possible to change one type of backup into an another.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting both a new Windows Phone and a new phone number, use our Change Number feature before you back up and transfer your chat history to the new phone.

Transfer your chats with SD card:

1. Make sure your phone has an SD card slot and you have made a backup on your SD card. Learn how to back up your chat history in this FAQ article.
2. Remove the SD card from your old Windows Phone and insert it into your new Windows Phone.
3. After inserting the SD card to your new phone, install WhatsApp from the Microsoft Store and verify your number.
4. WhatsApp will ask you to restore your chats and media from a backup when you verify your number. Simply tap "Restore" when prompted to do so.

Transferring your chat history can take a while to complete, depending on your Internet connection and back up size. Make sure you are connected to a strong and stable Wi-Fi connection. Please leave your phone connected to a power source until the back up completes.

You can also email your chat history to keep a record of your chats.

Comment: Question is about transferring data from an android phone. Your answer doesn't address the question please review it.